# How to Achieve this type shaded text Ui in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image: Like This Image Example]

How we can do this type if the number was 28 the before 2 digit 00 will be shaded if it was 5 before 3 digits will be shaded in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split them into two `Text` widgets. For example like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final data = ['0028', '1234', '0002', '0005', '1010', '0101', '0000'];

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var splitIndex = data[index].indexOf(RegExp('[^0]'));
            if (splitIndex == -1) splitIndex = data[index].length;
            return Row(children: [
              Text(data[index].substring(0, splitIndex),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
              Text(data[index].substring(splitIndex, data[index].length)),
            ]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope the below code will help you :



class ShadedNumberInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShadedNumberInputState createState() => _ShadedNumberInputState();
}

class _ShadedNumberInputState extends State<ShadedNumberInput> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  String _lastValue = '';

  void _onChanged(String value) {
    // Determine how many digits to shade based on the input value
    int numDigitsToShade = 0;
    if (value.isNotEmpty && _lastValue != value) {
      if (int.parse(value) == 28) {
        numDigitsToShade = 2;
      } else if (int.parse(value) == 5) {
        numDigitsToShade = 3;
      }
      _lastValue = value;
    }

    // Update the text controller with the shaded value
    String shadedValue = value.padLeft(value.length + numDigitsToShade, '0');
    _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: shadedValue,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: shadedValue.length),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onChanged: _onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This widget should do the trick, alter the TextStyle to suit your needs and you might want to update text to be an int if you're only going to deal with numbers!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PadString extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int charCount;
  final String padChar;

  const PadString({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.charCount = 4,
    this.padChar = "0",
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var padCount = charCount - text.length;

    return Row(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < padCount; i++)
          Text(
            padChar,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```